# How the user instance of systemd is started?

Tags: tizen, systemd

So, I've read the porting guide (https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Porting_Guide). There is a section named "Tizen Bootup Overview".

How the user instance of systemd is started in Tizen? I know when it is started, but who does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user session in Tizen is started through `user-session@app.service` service file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/` directory.